# Problems with opening certain .onion websites

Tags: onion-services

I'm hunting for nice cannabis strains but when I use .onion website links with Tor program, only a few of them open up but everything that has better reviews and products (for example, DeepWeb, SilkRoad, Black Market etc) won't open up. It says the page can't be loaded, but my network is just fine and I know some people are using the same links perfectly fine. Is there a problem with my laptop or with Tor itself? What can I do? I'd really appreciate all the responses!

Comment: could you post an example of one that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Also make sure your clock is set correct. This can also cause issues if its incorrect. Also check logs.

Answer (score -1):

lucy goosey check this out darling

page down, right side shows which sites are up, good reviews or go to http://dnstats.net/

[DeepDotWeb](http://www.deepdotweb.com/2013/10/28/updated-llist-of-hidden-marketplaces-tor-i2p/)

motsue need more confetti